# What is the meaning when a SelectionKey instance call interestOps(0)?

Tags: java, nio

What is the meaning when a [`SelectionKey`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SelectionKey.html) instance call [`interestOps(0)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SelectionKey.html#interestOps-int-)?
0 is not the enum value defined in `SelectionKey`. What is the function of `interestOps(0)`?

Answer (score 3):

There are four operations: `OP_ACCEPT`, `OP_CONNECT`, `OP_READ`, and `OP_WRITE`. These aren't enum values, they are integer constants. The values can be bitwise ORed `|` together if you are interested in multiple operations. For instance:

```
selectionKey.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ | SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
```

`interestOps(0)` clears the interest set, setting none of the bits.

If those constants were `enum Operation` values then `interestOps(0)` would become `interestOps(EnumSet.noneOf(Operation.class))`.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the meaning when a SelectionKey instance call interestOps(0)?

It means there are no operations of interest in this selection key. `Selector.select()` will ignore it.

> 0 is not the enum value defined in SelectionKey.

I don't know what this means. No enum value is defined in `SelectionKey`.

> What is the function of interestOps(0)?

Same question, same answer.